How to Fetch File Name from Default Upload Feature in Telerik File Explorer and Set Character Limit Validation
I am using the Telerik File Explorer in my web application, and I need assistance with the default file upload feature. I have two specific requirements:
Fetching the File Name: How can I programmatically retrieve the file name from the default upload feature in Telerik File Explorer when a user selects a file?
Setting Character Limit Validation: I want to implement a validation rule to limit the file name to a maximum of 100 characters. If the file name exceeds this limit, an error message should appear, instructing the user to shorten the file name.
I tried to fetch the select file from below code. But it wasn't successful.
    function onClientFileSelected(radUpload, eventArgs) {
         var input = eventArgs.get_fileInputField();
         alert(input);
    }

Note:
<telerik:RadUpload id="RadUpload1" runat="server" allowedfileextensions=".zip,.txt" onclientfileselected="onClientFileSelected" />

This hasn't used inside my .ascx file.
Default Upload
Above image is when the user selected a invalid file, How do i add a new validation message for the character length.
current code in .ascx file
<div class="file-container">
<telerik:RadFileExplorer ID="RadFileExplorer1" runat="server" OnClientLoad="onClientLoad" OnClientItemSelected="onClientItemSelected"
    OnClientFileOpen="onClientFileOpen" OnClientFolderChange="onClientFolderChange" OnClientFilesDropping="onClientFilesDropping">
</telerik:RadFileExplorer>

<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" CssClass="FileUploaderWindow" Behaviors="Close, Move" OnClientClose="onClientClose" runat="server"></telerik:RadWindowManager>

